# MQTT-over-Websockets doent work on remote server

Tags: node.js, mqtt

I'm using a deploy like
https://medium.com/@lelylan/how-to-build-an-high-availability-mqtt-cluster-for-the-internet-of-things-8011a06bd000

now I want to send message
form the browser to my device (for now a fake in my localhost) so
if I do like

both broker client.hmtl and client.js are on my localhost

### client.html

```
<html>
  <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
  <script src="./browserMqtt.js"></script>
  <script>
  var device = { nickname: 'wbk0da8v9l2wewmi', secret: 'mysecret' };
  var msg  = 'devices/' + device.nickname + '/msg' ;
  var var client = mqtt.connect(
      { host: 'localhost', 
      port: 3000,
    username: device.nickname,  
      password: device.secret  });  
  client.subscribe(msg);
  client.on('message', function(topic, payload) {
      console.log('My message ',[topic, payload].join(": "));
      client.end();
  });
  client.publish(msg, "hello world client html !");
    </script> 
    </body>

</html>
```

### client.js

```
var device = { nickname: 'wbk0da8v9l2wewmi', secret: 'mysecret' };



var msg  = 'devices/' + device.nickname + '/msg' ;

var mqtt = require('mqtt');

console.log(msg);


var client = mqtt.connect('mqtt://localhost:1883',{  username: device.nickname,  password: device.secret   });

client.subscribe(msg);

client.on('connect', function() {
    console.log('Client successfully connected');
    client.on('message', function(topic, message) {
        console.log('received from', topic, message);
        client.publish(msg, 'Client 1 is alive.. Test Ping msg! ' + Date());
        client.end();
    });
});
```

It works fine.

But if I have the broker and the client.html on a remote server
leaving the client.js on my localhost with

```
var device = { nickname: 'wbk0da8v9l2wewmi', secret: 'mysecret' };



var msg  = 'devices/' + device.nickname + '/msg' ;

var mqtt = require('mqtt');

console.log(msg);


var client = mqtt.connect('mqtt://204.151.191.103:1883',{  username: device.nickname,  password: device.secret   });

client.subscribe(msg);

client.on('connect', function() {
    console.log('Client successfully connected');
    client.on('message', function(topic, message) {
        console.log('received from', topic, message);
        client.publish(msg, 'Client 1 is alive.. Test Ping msg! ' + Date());
        client.end();
    });
});
```

it doesn't work.

I'm wondering what's could be the problem ?
I'm doing something wrong ?

### UPDATE

When I say it doen't work I mean

I can see

> Client successfully connected

from the console window (when I run client.js)

but I can't see any message both client

> received from

(the on message event isn't triggered)

and browser side

> My message

(the on message event isn't triggered)

when I run client.html in the firebug console I've got

Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://myserver.me:3000/.

Comment: Have you opened any required firewall ports on the remote machine? Also when you say it doesn't work, how doesn't it work, what error messages do you get?

Comment: Yes, I've I can see Client successfully connected form console window. I've updated the post.

Comment: when I run client.html in the firebug console I've got

Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://myserver.me:3000/.

Answer (score 0):

On client.html did you also change host: 'localhost', port: 3000 for the remote one ?

Did you connect sucessfully to 204.151.191.103 port 1883 with another MQTT client like MQTT.fx or mosquitto_pub ?